# Agnostic Development

Tags: haxe

I'm getting into Haxe. I do really love the agnostic core language,
but as soon as i run into a "complex" piece of software I need to use the designed language lib (`flash.Lib`, or `js.Lib`, etc).

Plus I always need lots of external libraries (tweening, image processing, etc, etc) that are all language specific.

Any hints on how I should approach the problem? Is there a "safe" agnostic libraries list?

How would you develop an application that should run on the Flash Player, but also on a JavaScript VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you mostly need is [NME](http://www.haxenme.org/).

HaxeNME is the best way to do some cross-platform graphic application.

You can also take a look at [Jeash](http://jeash.com/), thus it is included on NME.

You can also use [conditionnal compilation](http://haxe.org/ref/conditionals)

Also, [a lot of Haxelib](http://lib.haxe.org/t/cross) Libraries are tagged with "Cross", which means that they should be cross platforms.

Regards,

Comment: Yeah, I've developed a few cross platform libraries and that's definitely the way to go: you create a library that deals with all the cross platform quirks (using conditional compilation) and then provides a single, simple API that can be used no matter which target you're on.  This is how NME works, and this is how some of my libraries (and probably most cross platform libraries) work.

Answer (score 1):

If I were developing for both Flash and Javascript I would probably use a MVC library and build two distinct views, one for each language.

With PureMVC you could use the same model as well as view mediators regardless of which platform you were using. The only extra work would be that you would need to wrap all of your view components so that the javascript view acts very much like the flash view.

https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-haxe-standard-framework/wiki